# How many $7$ digit numbers in the form $a_7a_6...a_1$ such $\forall i \in (1,6)$ $a_{i+1}\geq a_i$

Tags: combinatorics

How many $7$ digit numbers in the form $a_7a_6...a_1$ such $\forall i \in (1,6)$ $a_{i+1}\geq a_i$, $0$ leading not allowed.

It is easy if the condition was $\forall i \in (1,6)$ $a_{i+1} > a_i$, I have recognized that I have $10$ ways to put $a_1$ the next $a_2$ has $C_{10-a_1}^1$ ways and so on. can you help me please.

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? What difficulty are you having?

Comment: I don't know how to start my analyse

Comment: In that case, it can often be a good idea to start simpler. What if you were looking for 2-digit numbers instead? That's small enough to just count directly. Can you find a good systematic way to count them?

Comment: Why not? What don't you understand? Can you solve a siimpler problem such as "How many 3 digit numbers $abc$ are there such that $a \ge b$ and $b\ge c$?"

Comment: I have tried 2 digits numbers, but the problem was difficult to go for 3 or more digits using the same analyse

Comment: The way I interpret the condition is that $a_7 \ge a_6$ and $a_2 \ge a_1$. This means that $a_5, a_4, a_3$ can be any digits.

Comment: See [How many ten digit decreasing numbers are there when its digits form a decreasing sequence such that each digit is not larger than the preceding one?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2477404) and [How many five digit number can be formed such that their numbers counted from left to right creates a decreasing sequence?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2331080)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How many ten digit decreasing numbers are there when its digits form a decreasing sequence such that each digit is not larger than the preceding one?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2477404/how-many-ten-digit-decreasing-numbers-are-there-when-its-digits-form-a-decreasin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For such a number, the $a_i+i$ form a srtictly increasing sequence of numbers $\in\{1,\ldots, 16\}$, and this can be identified with a size-$7$ subset of this size-$16$ set. Hence there are $16\choose 7$ such numbers, starting from $0000000$ corresponding to $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ and running up to $9999999$ corresponding to $\{10,11,12,13,14,15,16\}$. Only one case of leading zero (namely $0000000$) needs to be removed, so the final answer is 
$${16\choose 7}-1.$$

Comment: This is a great solution and its the "smart approach" to this problem. Don't know why you got downvoted.

Comment: What does number does {1,3,5,7,9,11,13} correspond to?

Answer (score 0):

*Although it has been clarified that the "alternative" condition was intended, I shall leave this answer to the wrong problem.*

---

If $i=7$ then there is no $a_{i+1}$ so it seems to me that the condition $\forall i \in (1,7) \text{ } a_{i+1} \ge a_i$ is badly written. I suggest this should be $\forall i \in (1,6) \text{ } a_{i+1} \ge a_i$.

The way I interpret the condition is that $a_7 \ge a_6$ and $a_2 \ge a_1$. This means that $a_5, a_4, a_3$ can be any digits.

(Alternatively it might be intended that the digits **do not increase** from left to right : $\forall i \in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)=(1..6) \text{  } a_{i+1} \ge a_i$.)

So there are 3 independent problems :

(a) in how many ways $P_a$ can you write a 2-digit number $a_7a_6$ such that $a_7 \ge a_6$ with $a_7 \ne 0$?

(b) in how many ways $P_b$ can you write a 3-digit number $a_5a_4a_3$ with no restrictions (so $a_5$ can be $0$)?

(c) in how many ways $P_c$ can you write a 2-digit number $a_2a_1$ with $a_2 \ge a_1$ (again $a_2$ can be $0$)?

Finally combine all 3 results : $P=P_a \times P_b \times P_c$.

Comment: $a_7 \geq a_6\geq a_5\geq a_4\geq a_3\geq a_2\geq a_1$